# Software for voice editing and recording

Tags: windows, audio, audio-recording, audio-editing

I have started a new hobby, I want to sing covers mostly for myself. I bought the [U-PHORIA Studio](https://www.thomann.de/fr/behringer_u_phoria_studio.htm?glp=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwlN32BRCCARIsADZ-J4vtWX1f3ZxBV1CP3RImyU38nQRhIT44PBu2xZ5iyJwfELe4F-QFoRQaAoHXEALw_wcB). Now I want to know which software to use.
The instruction guide recommends [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) although I am also inclined to [Adobe Audition](https://www.adobe.com/products/audition.html) as I have used Adobe products before and like them.

Also, I will only use this microphone for voice recording (singing) so I won't mind a software specifically designed for voice which may be either easier to use (because of less tools) and/or more things that can be done to the voice. Maybe what about [Auto-Tune](https://www.antarestech.com/)? What are the relationship between autotune and audacity for example? are there alternatives or they are meant to be complementary?

Sorry for this newbie question! Also heard Reaper is a good soft.

---

Seeing some more info. I found that LOGIC PRO X has actually some great autotune soft. Here is an [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0Y1Q8Zde4w) that seams super intuitive. When I google video tutorials to autotune it does not seem so intuitive.

Autotune is something I will have to use for sure when editing I think. LOGIC PRO X is not an option however because I use Windows.

Answer (score 3):

[Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) is:

- Very good
- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Quite easy to use
- Available for multiple platforms
- Can do cleaver tricks like removing repetitive background noise or increasing tempo without changing pitch.

Strongly recommend giving it a try before you look at anything else.